# Linux/ make folder with date name

Tags: linux

I try to create folder in my server with the current date.

So I wrote the next lines:

```
$ mkdir # date +”%d-%m-%Y”
cd # date +”%d-%m-%Y”
```

and save it as `.sh`, But for somme reasom it doesn't work. What can be the reason?

Comment: The `#` symbol, to the shell, is the start of a comment extending to the end of the line.

Comment: And the $ is used to indicate a prompt. You don't need to type it.

Comment: Instead of `”`, you should use the normal `"`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use

```
mkdir "$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
cd "$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
```

In the extreme case a day passes between the first and the second statement, that won't work. Change it to:

```
d="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
mkdir "$d"
cd "$d"
```

Explanation: The `$(...)` returns the output from the subcommands  as a string, which we store in the variable `d`.

(Quoted the variables as suggested by tripleee)

Comment: I was going to suggest using a temporary variable just because it's cleaner, but I didn't consider the case of the day changing during the script. Nice catch.

Comment: Top it with proper double quotes around variable interpolations. They are not strictly necessary here, but we don't want the newbies to pick up bad habits.